# Testing the convergence of complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi I am working on the following problem:
Test whether the following series is absolute convergent/convergent or divergent

(a) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(1+i)^n}{(2i)^n}$

(b) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^22^n}{(1+i)^n}$

(c) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

For (a) I applied ratio test and I got $$\Bigg|\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n}\Bigg|=\Bigg|\frac{(n+1)(1+i)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}}\frac{(2i)^n}{n(1+i)^n)}\Bigg|=...\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\Bigg|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\Bigg|<1$$ Hence the series in (a) is absolutely convergent as well as convergent.

For (b) I applied Ratio test again and I got $$\Bigg|\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n}\Bigg|=...=|1-i|>1$$ Hence the series is divergent.

For (c) the ratio test is inconclusive, so I separated the real and imaginary parts and found out they are conditionally convergent.

I am not quite sure about (a) and (b) specially at the end part. Could anyone help me to decide whether my solution is right or wrong. Also is there any other way to solve these problems? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For $(c)$ the series is convergent but not absolutly  since $|z_n|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam That doesn't show why the series converges conditionally.  It only shows that it doesn't converges absolutely.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, Sorry for the typo. I found it conditionally convergent. Thank you.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

For Problem $(c)$, note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{4N}\frac{i^n}{\sqrt n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n}}-i\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n}}-i\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2n-1}}
\end{align}$$

---

For the other problems, $(a)$ and $(b)$, application of the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) immediately gives, respectively

$$\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{n(1+i)^n}{(2i)^n}\right|^{1/n}&=\sqrt{2}/2<1\implies \,\,\text{the series converges absolutely}\\\\
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{n^2\,2^n}{(1+i)^n}\right|^{1/n}&=\sqrt{2}>1 \implies \,\,\text{the series diverges}
\end{align}$$

Comment: (c) is not the problem, I did that. Is my solution to (a) and (b) right?

Comment: @mint Yes your $(a)$ and $(b)$ answers are fine.

Comment: @mint I've edited to provide another, perhaps more efficient approach using the root test.  -Mark